# modified lvalue error

Tags: c++

```
void mouse(int btn,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 0;
    if( btn == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 1;
    if( btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 2;
    theta[axis]+=2.0;
    if( theta[axis]>360 ) theta[axis]-=360;
    display();
}
```

Identifier `btn`. The above code is giving me **modified lvalue error**. I don't know why. Please help me to fix this out. Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: Which error does it show? We're not GCCs or clangs, you know

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages, don't paraphrase them. No compiler will say "modified lvalue error".

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about this: `state = GLUT_DOWN` ...

```
void mouse(int btn,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 0;
    if( btn == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 1;
    if( btn == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 2;
    theta[axis]+=2.0;
    if( theta[axis]>360 ) theta[axis]-=360;
    display();
}
```

... in the if statements. It assigns the values - it does not compare. If assigned value is not equal to `0`, it's evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
if( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state = GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 0;
                                     ^
                                     assignment
```

It is attempting to assign `GLUT_DOWN` to `btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state`, which is not a modifiable lvalue.

In the above statement, I *think* you <s>want</s> intended to compare, i.e.

```
if( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN ) axis = 0;
                                     ^^
                                     equality comparison
```

Comment: Assigning to `state` is fine, although not the intent. The source of the error is that `state` is not the left hand side of the assignment.

Comment: To clarify: modifying an lvalue, such as `state`, is not an error (OP is misquoting an error message). That you can assign to them is pretty much their defining trait. The problem is that `state` is *not* what the code is trying to modify.

Comment: Yes, the point of problem needed to be more specific. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote "=" instead of "==", and "=" has a very low precedence, much lower than your other operators.

This means that your code is actually trying to do

```
(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state) = GLUT_DOWN
```

that is, you're trying to assign a value to `btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state`.

Replacing "=" with "==" should fix it.